# This location could not be displayed on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, usb-drive

I am facing this problem. I plugged in my flash drive of 16 GB and removed it. Before that I ejected it properly but when I'm connecting it again to my Ubuntu laptop it displays this error, "This location could not be displayed".

I searched for a solution but found none for my particular one. So someone please tell me how to get rid of this problem. The drive shows well on Windows platform (on different laptop). The one I have is only Ubuntu installed.

Comment: PLug in ur usb stick, try 'mount -v -a'  without the quotes and and post the log here.

Comment: @ We are Borg:- Thanks for your help but the issue got solved without doing anything. I formatted my drive on a Windows laptop and when I connected it to my Ubuntu laptop there was no problem.

Comment: Good for you...if incase there is data on the drive, this could have been a problem.

Comment: @ We are Borg:- May be but the drive connected well on Windows and I was able to copy the data elsewhere before formatting.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I formatted my USB drive on a Windows laptop and connected it to my Ubuntu laptop. It showed fine.